# Why does ReSharper warn at Char.ToString() when not specifying CultureInfo explicitly?

Tags: c#, resharper, cultureinfo

I was wondering why ReSharper does warn me, when I'm trying to convert a char to a string without giving a specific culture info.

Is there any case, where it could be converted differently on two systems?

**Example:**

```
var str = ' '.ToString();
```

The following ReSharper warning will pop up by default:

> Specify a culture in string conversion explicitly.

Comment: What is the warning exactly? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  based on your problem.

Comment: What is the code exactly?

Comment: This is a good question that I'm asking myself lots of times. But you need to add example code and the exact message

Comment: I suppose the warning fires on all classes/structs that have an overload which accepts `CultureInfo`. Since a IFormatProvider could return anything based on the input, it may be the case that it *should* return something different,

Comment: [Fixed in R# 9.0, apparently](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-372088)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because ReSharper sees that the type implements `IConvertible` which has `ToString(IFormatProvider)`.

`System.Char` by itself does not expose a public method with that signature, even though the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates it does:

[image: Char.ToString overloads]

If you look at the overload with the `IFormatProvider` parameter you will see this notice:

> Implements
>   `IConvertible.ToString(IFormatProvider)`

and this remark:

> The *provider* parameter is ignored; it does not participate in this operation.

ReSharper just notices the presence of that method, and the call to `ToString` without a `IFormatProvider` and thus complains, in this case you can safely disregard it.

Comment: I like this answer, but it does not answer my (second) question directly yet: Are there any sideeffects between different systems disregarding it. I'd like to have a direct conclusion under all the information you gave me. :)

Comment: No, "you can safely disregard it". A single character will be converted to a string with a single character, there's no conversion happening here.

Comment: The [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,9f693c2a17b40531) also shows this to be true.

Answer (score -2):

I found this http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx

> Some of the oddities of Unicode lead to oddities in string and
>   character handling. Many of the string methods are culture-sensitive -
>   in other words, what they do depends on the culture of the current
>   thread. **For example, what would you expect "i".toUpper() to return?
>   Most people would say "I", but in Turkish the correct answer is "İ"**
>   (Unicode U+0130, "Latin capital I with dot above")

Comment: That's not the point here. There is not `ToUpper` or `ToLower` methods in this case.